# How do I prove this identity involving polar coordinates and $\nabla$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, polar-coordinates, chain-rule

Given that
$$\begin{aligned}
&x=r\cos(\theta),\\
&y=r\sin(\theta),\\
& \qquad \text{and}\\
&x^2+y^2=r^2
\end{aligned}$$
Use the chain rule to show that $\nabla=\mathbf{\hat{r}}\frac\partial{\partial r}+\mathbf{\hat{\theta}}\frac1r\frac\partial{\partial\theta}.$

I derived that $\,\mathbf{\hat{r}}=\cos(\theta)\mathbf{\hat{\text{i}}}+\sin(\theta)\mathbf{\hat{\text{j}}}\,$ and that  $\,\mathbf{\hat{\theta}}=-\sin(\theta)\mathbf{\hat{\text{i}}}+\cos(\theta)\mathbf{\hat{\text{j}}}.$ But I can't seem to gro from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show  $$\nabla=\mathbf{\hat{r}}\frac\partial{\partial r}+\mathbf{\hat{\theta}}\frac1r\frac\partial{\partial\theta}.$$

we need to find $\frac {\partial u}{\partial x}$ and $ \frac {\partial u}{\partial y}$ in terms of $r$ and $\theta.$

Note that $ \frac {\partial u}{\partial r}=     \frac {\partial u}{\partial x}   \frac {\partial x}{\partial r} +    \frac {\partial u}{\partial y}   \frac {\partial y}{\partial r} =  \frac {\partial u}{\partial x}\cos(\theta) +   \frac {\partial u}{\partial y} \sin(\theta)$

Similarly $ \frac {\partial u}{\partial \theta}=     \frac {\partial u}{\partial x}   \frac {\partial x}{\partial \theta} +    \frac {\partial u}{\partial y}   \frac {\partial y}{\partial \theta} =  \frac {\partial u}{\partial x}(-r\sin(\theta)) +   \frac {\partial u}{\partial y}(r\cos(\theta))$

Solve  the above system for $ \frac {\partial u}{\partial x}$ and $ \frac {\partial u}{\partial y}$, and you will get the result.

Comment: Solving the above system we get $\partial_x = \cos(\theta) \partial_r - \sin(\theta)/r \partial_\theta$ and $\partial_y = \sin(\theta) \partial_r + \cos(\theta)/r \partial_\theta$. Isn't there a further logical step missing?